# Read the values from the jsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSONArray like below

```
System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));
//output
["4","3","2","1","3","5","6"]
```

How can i access the values inside the array. For Example if i want value 2 from the above array which is at index 2, what should i use to get the value

Comment: `jsonArray.get(2)` does not work?

Comment: Does `jsonArray.get(i).getInt(2)` work? It looks like you have a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes.. I have a 2-dimensional array.`jsonArray.get(i).getInt(2)` is not working..The method getInt(int) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: That's because if you just call `get`, it returns a java object. To return a `JSONObject`, you have to look for the methods that have `JSON` in their name, like `getJSONArray` - which is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `org.json.JSONArray`

```
String s = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getString(2);
```

should do the trick.